# How to update MySql Database in Netbeans IDE 8.1 using jsp?

Tags: java, mysql, database, jsp, netbeans

I am trying to make a registration page with around 10 details. But in no way am I able to update the database with those details. I have followed every procedure i found on every site including stackoverflow but still whenever i submit my form nothing happens. Like when i press the submit button it goes to another page and the address bar shows everything correctly but yet i don't know why there is no change in the database.  I am new to JSP and Netbeans, so i am not really aware of all the things. 
I used this as my guide http://www.studytonight.com/servlet/registration-form-example-in-servlet.php
P.S. I am new to JSP and netbeans, so i am not aware of a lot of things. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your code. Check for any exceptions in your logs and post them here

Comment: Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read and [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1):

First Create a class like this

```
class DBController {
        private $host = "Your IP";
        private $user = "User Name";
        private $password = "Password";
        private $database = "Your Database";


        function connectDB() {
            $conn = mysql_connect($this->host,$this->user,$this->password);
            return $conn;
        }

        function insertQuery($query) {
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            if (!$result) {
                die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
            } else {
                return $result;
            }       
        }


    }
    ?>
```

Create a text box

```
<input type="text" class="" name="patfirstname" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['patfirstname'])) echo $_POST['patfirstname']; ?>">
```

And a submit button

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
```

And in the same registration form create a post PHP function

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])== "POST")
{
    require_once("dbcontroller.php");
    $db_handle = new DBController(); 
   $query = "INSERT INTO new_table ( Name ) VALUES ( '" . $_POST["patfirstname"] . "');";
    $result = $db_handle->insertQuery($query);
}       

?>
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: PHP? Are you serious? He talked about Java and JSP.